# python - selenium give error tht geckodriver need to be in PATH (even though IT IS)

Tags: python, linux, selenium, path, geckodriver

So as the title said i try to work with selenium on python i got the geckodriver v0.26.0 for linux 32bit copied it on /usr/local/bin with chmod a+x (for all users):

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin# ls -la 
total 6268
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 May  7 19:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root    4096 May  3 15:06 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 6409830 May  7 19:04 geckodriver
```

i viewed all previous questions and answers but none of them helped.
The error keeps showing : 
WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 
i have tried also this line of code :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution for the next one who falls into this problem:

1. use the compatible geckodriver version (x64 or x86)
2. copy the file to /usr/local/bin with chmod +x
3. point to the driver from your code like this :

   browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")

Answer (score 0):

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

I had a similar issue when trying to import the driver using the above line of code i ended up fixing it by pointing directly to the executable rather than the folder it was stored in.

Comment: thank you for your reply, 
the executable is 'geckodriver' executable_path directs to file

Comment: Have you tried adding it as an environmental variable?

Comment: yes i tried adding it from download folder and other folders with "export PATH=$PATH:/path-to-fine/ "